# ggplot R scale x log10 limits not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have a variable `q` in a dataframe `t` I want to `limit` the `x_axis` with `log10` `scale`

```
#t$q
1.000000 2.500000 2.733333 3.032258 1.545455 1.967213 1.176471 1.000000 2.533333 3.136364 1.967213
ggplot(t,aes(x=q))+geom_freqpoly(binwidth=0.1)+scale_x_log10(limits=c(0,1))+scale_y_log10()
```

I got this error :

```
Error in if (diff(range) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log of 0 is negative infinity, so you would have a really long x axis! Try `limits=c(0.1, 1)` instead in the `ggplot` call.